# Filtering Twitter statuses by date (via API)

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to view twitter statuses for a particular day through the API? I figured this would be a pretty basic function, but after looking through the documentation and parameters it doesn't seem to be so straight forward. Has anyone done this through the API? I know it possible, b/c the Momento app for iPhone pulls it off flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the since and until parameters listed on http://search.twitter.com/operators. Be aware though that they only support year/month/day and the Search API only returns results for the last week or two. Anything older then that is not available. Any further filtering will havet to be done within your application.